# EF: How to query for local data

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

This is EF4. I have a SIMPLE question. Say if I add a few sales orders to the context object like:

```
Dim NewOrder = context.SalesOrders.CreateObject()
NewOrder.Number= 123
context.SalesOrders.AddObject(NewOrder)
```

I haven't called SaveChanges() yet and want to see if there's an order with Number=123 in the context using this:

```
context.SalesOrder.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Number=123)
```

Why in the world does this above query return Nothing? Is it searching the database instead of the local context object?

Comment: it would be fine if the `.FirstOrDefault` then `.AddObject`

Comment: @spajce: That's not the question at hand. The point here is that I want to search in the local context object first; something that is done in EF5 (as I am being told) by the 'context.SalesOrder.Local' member. I need its equivalent in EF4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search the local entities through the object state manager: (C# syntax, but the VB.NET equivalent should be obvious for you)

```
context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EntityState.Modified | EntityState.Unchanged).Select(entry => entry.Entity).OfType<SalesOrder>()
```

That is actually what `DbSet.Local` does behind the scenes too. It may be worth the effort to make this available on your context as a generic helper function.

Answer (score 0):

Is Number the primary key on the SalesOrder entity?

If so, you can just use .Find() as this first queries the local entities and only then queries the database if nothing is found in the local entities collection :

```
context.SalesOrders.Find(number);
```

Note that find can only accept the primary key and not lambdas as with other LINQ operations.

Comment: Yes. It is the PK. Where is the Find() method found (no pun intended :))?

Comment: `.Find()` is a `DbSet` method, it is not available for `ObjectSet`s.

Comment: I don't see any Find method in my entities. Is it something available in EF5 only, as hvd mentioned?

Comment: It is on the DbSet object (which I think in your case is  SalesOrders)